Bug? listings causes line breaks after slash outside of listings environments
Is this a bug? Look at this monstrosity:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog or I don't recall whatever/something.
    
\end{document}


Removing listings removes the problem:
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog or I don't recall whatever/something.
    
\end{document}



wow it's been there for 10 years looking at the duplicate @egreg reported. Surprised that doesn't come up more often (or that anyone uses typehtml, a very dubious package.)

@DavidCarlisle The package has underwent some changes in the last few months, maybe the OP's message will catch some attention, possibly if information about the issue solved with the patch of ten years ago is shown.

It sets the lccode of / to itself which makes it a letter that takes part in hyphenation. that seems.... unfortunate but
\lccode`\/=0


would restore things

And is it supposed to do that outside of listings environments?

@Gaussler I doubt it, you'd have to ask the maintainer

I wrote him an email.
